# Why are Firefox search suggestions so slow?

Tags: search, kubuntu, firefox

On Kubuntu 11.04, the search bar is quite slow when typing for queries. It displays everything fine, but will freeze for a second or two as I'm tying. I'm using the [Omnibar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/omnibar/) addon, so there is no dedicated search bar, just the address bar. I've tried removing the places.sqlite files, so I know it's not an issue with the history. Any ideas?

**Edit-**

Okay, I tried switching the Omnibar's settings to "slim" mode (it was on "rich and slim" previously). This causes the dropdown suggestions to be simple URLs, and this improved the responsiveness. It's still not quite as fast as, say, Chrome's "omnibar". Is this just a limitation of the plugin?

My connection speed is fairly fast, rated at 15Mbps. Google's own AJAX suggestions are very quick, so it's not a network limitation. This same thing has occurred on previous Ubuntu systems that I've used, and I've used the Omnibar plugin every time.

Comment: How fast is your internet connection? Do you have this issue only with this system?

Comment: @Michael: I updated the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is known to have [problems in Kubuntu](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=firefox%20problems%20kubuntu)'s KDE environment. I recommend you to install [InstantFox](http://www.instantfox.net/). It is better than OmniBar and updated too.